# How to print bibliography using biblatex just as enuemeration using keywords?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, keywords

I am using `biblatex` to print some of my papers in a section called `Publications` where this section produced by the following command  should not be considered as section.

```
\printbibliography[title=Publications, keyword=mypub,heading=bibnumbered,resetnumbers=true]
```

This section is just to show that these are my publications.

I have turned on `defernumbers = true` in

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,maxbibnames=6,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
```

I have a separate chapter as reference where I want all the references to be appear whichever I have cited in the document (including some of my papers). Numbering should be `[1], [2],...`

But I dont know why the below behavior.

[image]

### MWEB:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,maxbibnames=6,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@Article{mypub1,
  Title                    = {title of the paper},
  Author                   = {Author A},
  Journal                  = {Bulletin of something},
  Year                     = {2018},
  Note                     = {(Communicated)},
  Keywords                 = {mypub}
}

          @article{ref1,
            author    =   {AuthorB, Someone},
            title     =   {Some Great Title},
            journal   =   {Best Journal},
            year      =   3019,
            pages     =   {32--39},
            volume    =   3,
            keyword     = {mypublication},
            number    =   4
            }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Here is some text with a citation \cite{ref1}. 

Here is some more text using the old key \cite{mypub1}.

\printbibliography[title=Publications, keyword=mypub,heading=bibnumbered,resetnumbers=true]

\printbibliography[title=References, heading=bibnumbered,resetnumbers=true]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do. And more importantly I don't quite understand how you got the undesired output. Please consider adding an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that reproduces the issue - it need not and should not be long, it is enough if you include two or three entries to demonstrate the issue. Do you cite one of your publications? What happens if you want to add one of your publications to the bibliography as well?

Comment: @samcarter  I have added an MWEB and edited the quesiton too. Thank you for the link which helped to produce one in the same manner.

Comment: `\printbibliography[title=References, notkeyword=mypub, heading=bibnumbered, resetnumbers=true]` for the second `\printbibliography`?

Comment: @moewe This didnot work. It removes the references in the `References` section. I have cited some of my paper works also in my document. That should come in the `Reference` section without any doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easiest to have your list of publications in a separate refsection. That refsection is completely independent of the rest of your document and uses a different numbering than the rest of your document. To avoid confusion you may want to change the format of the label in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,maxbibnames=6]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{my.bib}
@Article{mypub1,
  Title    = {title of the paper},
  Author   = {Author A},
  Journal  = {Bulletin of something},
  Year     = {2018},
  Note     = {(Communicated)},
  Keywords = {mypub}
}

@article{ref1,
  author    =   {AuthorB, Someone},
  title     =   {Some Great Title},
  journal   =   {Best Journal},
  year      =   2019,
  pages     =   {32--39},
  volume    =   3,
  keyword     = {mypublication},
  number    =   4,
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
Here is some text with a citation \cite{ref1}. 

Here is some more text using the old key \cite{mypub1}.

\begin{refsection}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Publications, keyword=mypub,heading=bibnumbered]
\end{refsection}

\printbibliography[title=References, heading=bibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you are using the legacy BibTeX backend you'll have to do more compilation steps than usual if you use `refsection`s. With BibTeX you have to run BibTeX for each used section. I absolutely recommend switching over to Biber, where all of this is handled automatically (replace `backend=bibtex` with `backend=biber` and run Biber, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864)).

If you insist on using BibTeX instead of the usual LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX run you will have to do (assuming your `.tex` file is called `test.tex`)

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
bibtex test1-blx
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

So you need and extra BibTeX-run on `test1-blx`. All of this is mentioned in the `.log` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But one of your suggestion in other questions about using `refsegment` worked well.

Comment: I have no idea why that behaviour when `refsegment` works but not `refsection`

Comment: I dont why still the problem of getting repeated number in the `refsegment` comes. When the references in the section Publicaitons repeats it takes that label only. https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQDpo.png

Comment: @David How do `refsection`s not work for you? Is the output of the MWE not what you want? Is the output different in your actual document? What did you try? Do you get a warning or error message? I did not suggest `refsegment`s because they cause exactly the unfortunate numbering problem you highlighted in your last screenshot. `refsection`s avoid that.

Comment: `Empty bibliography` in log file as warning

Comment: @David See the edit. Of course the real answer is: switch to Biber.

Comment: thank you. I have changed to `biber` and it did the job.